# Best Practice: Website Localizations containing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, internationalization

I am working on a Javascript MVC website using Ember / Handlebars that needs to support internationalization.  I already have the code to do the translations, but am curious about what is the best practice for localizing big blocks of text (mutliple paragraphs, lists, etc).  Is it better to localize each paragraph, list item separately or to have the localization contain the HTML?

HTML:

```
<p>{{i18n first_paragraph}}</p>
<p>{{i18n second_paragraph}}</p>
<ul>
  <li>{{i18n first_item}}</li>
  <li>{{i18n second_item}}</li>
  <li>{{i18n third_item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Localization File:

```
first_paragraph: 'some text',
second_paragraph: 'some text',
first_item: 'some text',
second_item: 'some text',
third_item: 'some text'
```

**VS.**

HTML:

```
{{i18n page_content}}
```

Localization File:

```
page_content: '<p>some text</p><p>some text</p><ul><li>some text</li><li>some text</li><li>some text</li></ul>
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I don't want see html in localization files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is much more canonical. Why? Because you're abstracting the localisation (which is logic performed on data entities: in the localisation case, strings) from the semantic markup.

This might not seem that important right now, but what happens when you suddenly want to support another language? If you've abstracted your localisation to - in your case - a Handlebars Helper, you can add translations in an array within that Helper. If your localisation is jumbled up with your markup, then you'll have to trawl through your localisation files in a sloppy (time-consuming, and error-prone) way.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning toward this.